# Ubuntu 17.10 Nautilus "save as" very slow

Tags: nautilus

I recently experienced the issue that opening the first file manager window, or saving a document with "save as" is really slow. It takes 30 seconds for the menu to appear to let me save the document.

Comment: This is not a question.  I understand you might want to share your own knowledge, but you have to word the question *as* a question, and then publish your solution/answer *as* an answer to the question.

Comment: I have removed the solution part from the question. But you can find it [here](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1015265/1). Please post the solution part in the "Your Answer" field below. It's completely okay to answer your own question and accept your answer.

Comment: I though it was related to the recent file memory. But it did not help.
Instead,  I noticed that starting Nautilus in terminal I have this error message:
`initializing nautilus-dropbox 2015.10.28 error creating proxy: error calling startservicebyname for org.gtk.vfs.mtpvolumemonitor: timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24) nautilus-share-message: called "net usershare info" but it failed: failed to`
I never had a problem with dropbox before